# Как получить submit от ajaxSubmitButton?

Tags: yii

Есть форма(yii1)

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
    'method' => 'get',
    'id' => 'MyForm'
));
?>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Find'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

И файл js
 $('#myForm').submit(function(){
        alert(1);
    });
```

Когда нажимаю отправить на форме, то срабатывает alert.

Мне нужно заменить submitButton на ajaxSubmitButton, как мне теперь в js теперь определить что было сделано submit?

Comment: Вы хотите отправить форму без перезагрузки ajax?

Comment: @ultimatum , да

Comment: в синтаксисе yii могу немного запутаться, но по классике могу объяснить, или Вы уже сделали?

Comment: @ultimatum еще актуально

Comment: все получилось ?

Comment: @ultimatum в процессе, походу ошибка в другом, но за данное пояснение спасибо, многое понял.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишу в классическом стиле, на yii сами перенесете :

html:

```
<form id="form_id" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="input_name"/>
    <input type="text" name="input_name2"/>
    <input type="text" name="input_name3"/>
    <div onclick="sendForm()" >Отправить</div>
</form>
```

js:

```
 <script>
    function sendForm() {
        var data_form = $('form').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",                //метод
            url: your_URL ,              //URL на который отправляем запрос
            data: data_form,            //данные из формы
            success: function() {       //код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
                alert("Ваше сообщение отправлено!");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Реализация через `div`. Вроде ничего не пропустил.

P.S. - еще можно отменять действие по умолчанию для кнопки submit через `preventDefault();`